# How to increase the size of extjs's treelist 'micro' mode floater .x-treelist-floater?

Tags: extjs

When using the extjs treelist (from the admin demo) in 'micro' mode, the treelist flyout is to narrow for the tree node items I am trying to display.

The floater size defaults to 136px but I want it to be about 250px;
In the chrome console, I can make this happen with

```
Ext.select(".x-treelist-floater").setWidth(250);
```

How can I make this the default width of the treelist 'micro' mode flyout menu (.x-treelist-floater)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the config property 'expandedWidth'.

In the source, see Ext.overrides.list.TreeItem.privates.createFloater' for details.